# Angle of depression homework help

Tags: trigonometry

From the top of a 100 foot building , a man observes a car moving toward him. If the angle of depression of the car changes from 25 degrees to 35 degrees during the period of observation , how far does the car travel

Comment: This seems to be a fairly straightforward problem. What have you tried and where are you having difficulty?

Comment: This is not algebra: it's an exercise in trigonometry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The building is perpendicular to the ground so you can construct a right angled triangle

Comment: We don't know that the building is perpendicular to the ground. The person could be standing on top of the [leaning tower of Pisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa) for all we know.

Answer (score 1):

When the man sees the car at the first time, he observes it at 25°. Since the triangle $\Delta_{100\, ft-x_1-L_1}$ is a right triangle, when $x_1$ es the car fisrt position and $L_1$ the distance between the man and the car, we obtain
\begin{equation}
  L_1 = \frac{100\, ft}{\cos{25°}}.
\end{equation}
Similarly
\begin{equation}
  L_2 = \frac{100\, ft}{\cos{33°}}.
\end{equation}
Applying Cosines Law:
\begin{equation}
  \Delta x = x_2 - x_1 = \sqrt{L_1^2 + L_2^2 - 2L_1L_2\cos{8°}}.
\end{equation}

Comment: What makes you think that the triangle is a right angle triangle?

Comment: If we suppose the height is 100ft, then the angle of the building does not matter.